# Strange issue with NSAttributedString and layout

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label:
[image]

For the label I set attributedText:

```
let greenColor = UIColor.green
let thePrivacyPolicyAttribute = [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, .foregroundColor : greenColor] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
let thePrivacyPolicyAtrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "\(NSLocalizedString("thePrivacyPolicy", comment: ""))", attributes: thePrivacyPolicyAttribute)
let iAgreewithAtrStr = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Iagreewith", comment: ""))
let resultAtrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
resultAtrStr.append(iAgreewithAtrStr)
resultAtrStr.append(thePrivacyPolicyAtrStr)

privacyPolicyTextLabel.attributedText = resultAtrStr
```

On all devices result looks perfect, but on iPhone SE it looks:
[image]

I found that issue happens after executing `privacyPolicyTextLabel.attributedText = resultAtrStr`

On other devices (iPhone 6, 6 Plus,X) it looks perfect:
[image]

Why issue happens on iPhone SE and how to solve it?

UPDATE 1:

Attached `Content Hugging Priority` and Content `Compression Resistance Priority`

[image]

Comment: Seems like a `Content Hugging Priority` and/or `Content Compression Resistance Priority` problem. Could you please provide the values for that.

Comment: @EternalBlack Attached.

Comment: Can the string be actually wrapped? Doesn't it contain unbreakable spaces for example?